# FreeNAS not detecting hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, truenas

I have a FreeNAS box (OS install onto USB), with 2 hard drives in it. In the GUI its only showing 1 (ada0).

How do I make it detect the other one?

They are both showing in `dmesg`:

```
ada0 at ahcich1 bus 0 scbus1 target 0 lun 0                                     
ada0: <WDC WD20EZRX-00DC0B0 80.00A80> ATA-9 SATA 3.x device                     
ada0: 300.000MB/s transfers (SATA 2.x, UDMA6, PIO 8192bytes)                    
ada0: Command Queueing enabled                                                  
ada0: 1907729MB (3907029168 512 byte sectors: 16H 63S/T 16383C)                 
ada1 at ahcich2 bus 0 scbus2 target 0 lun 0                                     
ada1: <WDC WD20EZRX-00DC0B0 80.00A80> ATA-9 SATA 3.x device                     
ada1: 300.000MB/s transfers (SATA 2.x, UDMA6, PIO 8192bytes)                    
ada1: Command Queueing enabled                                                  
ada1: 1907729MB (3907029168 512 byte sectors: 16H 63S/T 16383C)    
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the root cause of the problem. The system hides the drive it uses not listed. If you are using a USB drive to your system, you will not have these problems.

Comment: The question explicitly says the I am using a USB drive.

Answer (score 0):

Have a nice day.

Well, we're not having more information to give a specific answer, but there are some points to look.

1) If you use GPARTED (if you have this), can you see the 2 drives? Because one problem could be an error when mounting the device.

2) If you run..

```
ls -al /dev/sd*
```

What is the result?

Comment: Please try to take note of the publication date of questions, asking the Original Poster to perform debugging steps 5 years later is unlikely to generate a response....